# CMake complains about debug library not found when building release

Tags: cmake

I'm waiting for the debug version of the library from an external source, they have delivered the release version already.

We use a Find... module to locate the library. This now results in something like:

```
optimized;libfoo.a;debug;foo-NOTFOUND
```

The CMakeLists.txt file:

```
...
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main ${foo})
```

Initiating the build with:

```
cmake source/dir -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

But cmake still complains about the debug library missing.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
foo
    linked by target "main" in directory source/dir
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Can I avoid this problem without changing our Find module or force setting the foo variable before each use?

Answer (score 0):

I've given it a try and you can't suppress this error. Looking at the responsible source code [`cmGlobalGenerator::CheckTargetProperties()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmGlobalGenerator.cxx#L1619) this check is only skipped with `INTERFACE` link libraries (which you obviously don't want since it would not link anything to `main`).

But you can declare a placeholder `IMPORTED` library of the name causing the error like:

```
add_library(foo-NOTFOUND STATIC IMPORTED)
```

To reproduce your problem and test the fix I've setup the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(FooNotFound)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0057 NEW)

set(foo "optimized;libfoo.a;debug;foo-NOTFOUND")
file(WRITE main.c "int main(void) { return 0; }")

if ("foo-NOTFOUND" IN_LIST foo)
    add_library(foo-NOTFOUND STATIC IMPORTED)
endif()

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main INTERFACE ${foo})
```